# how to print out a string and list in one line-python

Tags: python, formatting

```
a=[1,2,3]
print "the list is ：%"%(a)
```

I want to print out one line like this: `the list is：[1,2,3]`
I can not make it within one line and I have to do in this way:

```
print " the list is :%"
print a
```

I am wondering whether I can print out something that combine with string formatting and a list in ONE line.

Comment: Pretty sure you just do - print "the list is:", mylist

Comment: All you need is a comma

Answer (score 17):

The simplest way is what CodeHard_or_HardCode said in the comments. For Python 3 it would be:

```
a=[1,2,3]
print('This is a list', a)

This is a list [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 8):

I suggest using the string [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method, as it is recommended over the old `%` syntax.

```
print("the list is: {}".format(a))
```

Comment: This works in both Python 2 and Python 3!

Answer (score 2):

At least in Python 2.7.4., this will work:

```
print " the list is " + str(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a = [1,2,3]
print("the list is: %s" % a)
```

Comment: `%s` has been deprecated.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure that it's officially deprecated, but it's definitely discouraged.  In fact, this issue with formatting lists is directly referenced in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting): "The formatting operations described here [%] exhibit a variety of quirks that lead to a number of common errors (such as failing to display tuples and dictionaries correctly)."

Comment: I like the "".format() function for precise control, but for simple output (as OP requested), format % value is fine. Can you share a link that state's it's deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

```
print(f"the list is: {[1,2,3]}")
```

you will need to use python 3.7.1 or higher I believe, as this is when they added string interpolation

Answer (score -1):

```
a = [1,2,3]
print(f'the list is: {a}')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.